# How to compare two large files in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, terminal

I have two large files, 9600000 float values are written one by line by a C code.I know there are similar,they should actually be the same.How to compare them and see if there is any difference?
I have tried

```
diff --unchanged-group-format='' base.txt base4.txt
```

But this does not work it prints out the second file on the screen.

With

```
cmp base.txt base4.txt
base.txt base4.txt differ: byte 811221, line 62402
```

what does this mean,that 62402 lines are different?

Comment: `man cmp` (filler)

Comment: Do you actually want to see the differences if any, or do you just want to know if they differ without seeing the difference? If you just want to know if they're different, just do: `cmp base.txt base4.txt`. Also, this is not a programming question, so it's better to move this to the SuperUser site.

Comment: @NikosC. Take a look at edit please.

Comment: It means that the first difference found is at byte 811221 in the files, which is on line 62402.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from `cmp` means that the first difference between the files is at byte position `811221` in the files, which is on line `62402`. For example, if the two files are:

```
abcd
1234
wxyz
9876
```

and

```
abcd
1234
wqyz
9812
```

the output is:

```
file1.txt file2.txt differ: char 12, line 3
```

because on line `3` one file has `x` and the other file has `q`, and these are at byte position `12` (the newline characters are included in the byte count).

If you want to see all the differences, use the `-l` option.

```
$ cmp -l file1.txt file2.txt
12 170 161
18  67  61
19  66  62
```

Note that unlike `diff`, this isn't smart about insertions and deletions, it just compares each byte at each position. So if you insert or delete a character early in the file, everything after that will be shown as a mismatch.

Comment: Ok,but how to continue untill end of the file?

Comment: @RichardRublev: Continue and do what, exactly? `cmp` already told you that they differ. What additional information do you want? (I'm not dismissing your problem, just asking you to clarify it.)

Comment: @RichardRublev I've added the `-l` option to show all the mismatches instead of just the first.